# Which Open Source Proxy server could proxy based on server response? (HAProxy, Nginx...)

Tags: nginx, proxy, haproxy

For example, 
Client C send request to Proxy P, 
Proxy P forward all requests to Server S1 by default, 
but the response of some of the requests might be 301/302.

For those 301/302 response, is any proxy server possible to forward these requests again to Server S2 based on response code.

Comment: Is it that you want the proxy to specify the server to which the client should redirect to? You can use Nginx to (re)write the Location header so that by the time it does back to the client, it redirects to the server you want.

Comment: Thanks Pastafarian:
1. I don't want to return it to client.
2. it's a POST request, as I know if client receives a 301/302 response, it will initiate another GET request.  
So I wonder if any proxy server could proxy the original request again based on the S1's response code?

Comment: Oh I didn't see post in the original question.... you could use a reverse proxy but that would not just apply to a subset of response codes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either Apache's `ProxyPassReverse`  [Apache doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) or NGINX `proxy_redirect`
[NGINX doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html?#proxy_redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Nginx has a way to instruct the client to redirect to a given server by setting the `Location` header. Here's the documentation for it:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect

From the doc:

> Sets the text that should be changed in the `“Location”` and `“Refresh”` header fields of a proxied server response. Suppose a proxied server returned the header field `“Location: http://localhost:8000/two/some/uri/”`. The directive
>
> `proxy_redirect http://localhost:8000/two/ http://frontend/one/;`
>
> will rewrite this string to “Location: http://frontend/one/some/uri/”.

Comment: Thanks! Pastafarian:
Will Nginx use the original request to request the new url? since the original request is a POST request.

Comment: I believe this may be due to HTTP 1.1. spec. There is a special response code ```307``` which is supposed to instruct the client to keep the original method (like ```POST```) however there are still several caveats. You can see some more info on the subject here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect